# Error while trying to access Postgresql via java / spring

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Am getting the error while trying to communicate with the PostgreSQL.

The error I am getting is `Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver`

Another error I get is `java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.postgresql.Driver  from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`

My **`application.properties`** file looks like this:

```
spring.ds_items.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver 
spring.ds_items.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Dummy
spring.ds_items.username=root
spring.ds_items.password=root 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.ds_users.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver 
spring.ds_users.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Dummy2 
spring.ds_users.username=root
spring.ds_users.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and my **build.gradle** file dependencies looks like this ,

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38')
    sql ('org.postgresql:postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add the jar containing the driver...

Comment: If you are using Maven, add the Postgres driver to your dependencies

Comment: Am using Gradle !!

Comment: Are you sure there is a `postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4` dependency? The latest 9.1 build is 903 not 901  (and why are you using such an outdated driver?)

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no trailing **whitespace** for any of your application properties.

I ran into this on a new project, and was receiving the exact same error. I was pulling my hair out for hours until I realized that simple mistake.

---

If this doesn't do the trick then perhaps share a sample project on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Does your project include the appropriate driver `.jar` file?
Check here:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

It should go in your application's `lib/` directory, probably in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I assumed you were running a Tomcat server. It should go in your application's lib folder, probably in WEB-INF/lib or something. Wherever .jars normally go in your application.

Comment: Yah i done that also, But still it says  ( org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful )       and    ( Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver )

Comment: Can you tell me the path you added the .jar to, and which version you used? Make sure the permissions are OK on it? If you're on a Mac/Linux distro, run sudo chmod 777 postgresql_file_name_here.jar to make sure it can be accessed.

Comment: I edited my code, have a Look on Dependencies , Was i done any mistakes there ?

Comment: I don't think so - the postgresql driver you downloaded matches the version listed there under the sql dependency?